# How to read a page variable from a master page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variables, global-variables, master-pages

If a unique variable is assigned to each individual page; in this case `PageID`.

How can `PageID` be referenced from a master page on load?

**PAGE VB**

```
Partial Class Index
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Dim PageID As Integer = 1
End Class
```

**MASTER VB**

```
Partial Class MasterPage
  Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If PageID = 1 Then
    ...
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

I am aware this can be achieved with querystring however I am looking for a more efficient and secure solution due to the potential quantity of pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose a public property that returns that field, then you just have to cast the `Page` property in the `MasterPage` to the concrete type:

```
Dim index As Index = TryCast(Me.Page, Index)
If index IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim pageID As Int32 = index.PageID
End If
```

And in the `Index` class:

```
Partial Class Index
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private _PageID As Integer = 1
    Public Property PageID As Int32
        Get
            Return _PageID
        End Get
        Set(value As Int32)
            _PageID = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Since you want that in every page you need to define an interface. You could let them implement the same `Interface` for example `IPageable`:

```
Public Interface IPagable
    Property PageID As Int32
End Interface
```

Now let all pages implement it:

```
Partial Class Index
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Implements IPagable

    Private _PageID As Integer = 1
    Public Property PageID As Int32 Implements IPagable.PageID
        Get
            Return _PageID
        End Get
        Set(value As Int32)
            _PageID = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

and change the MasterPage accordingly:

```
Dim pageable As IPagable = TryCast(Me.Page, IPagable)
If pageable IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim pageID As Int32 = pageable.PageID
End If
```

Comment: Could the public property be declared in the App_Code folder and then the value defined on the page?

Comment: @Obsidion: i don't know, i've never used websites. Note that i've edited my answer to include an approach using interfaces.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you for the concise code.